# View the battery percentage of a device connected to the iPhone using the lightning port

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, batterylevel, lightning

Does someone know a way to read the battery percentage of a device that connected to the iPhone using the lightning port using Swift? If someone knows it impossible I would be really grateful as well.
And if it is indeed impossible should I do it using Bluetooth?

Thank you very much for all the helpers...

Answer (score 0):

If anything, it would be via the:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/index.html

And if the device supports battery level than probably the `UIDeviceBatteryState` and `UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification` would be another good place to start.

Comment: UIDevice* is only for the current device, not accesssories Im afraid

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'standardized' way for this - if your Accessory supports this via its proprietary protocol, ok - else you can't get this